# How to subscribe to a WebSocket in golang

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm converting a node js application to a Go one, but I don't understand how to use web sockets in Go.
I've read the documentation for the google ws and gorilla WebSocket but cannot find how to send a token on open, or how to send a ping to keep the connexion alive.

That's what I have so far using `github.com/gorilla/websocket`

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "mywebsocket.io", "http service address")

func listener() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "wss", Host: *addr, Path: "/?v=6&encoding=json"}

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for {
            _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                return
            }
            log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()
```

Of course I'm not sending anything so the connexion closes after the heartbeat interval

This is how I open the connexion in JS

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss:/mywebsocket.io/?v=6&encoding=json');
let seq;

ws.on('open', () => {
  const connect = {
    op: 2,
    d: {
      token: wsToken,
      properties: {
        $os: 'linux',
        $device: 'mac',
      },
    },
  };

  ws.send(JSON.stringify(connect));
});
```

Comment: Use [c.WriteMessage](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage) or [c.WriteJSON](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteJSON) to send the token after dialing the connection.

Comment: The gorilla websocket library has a way of keeping the connection alive via ping/pong.  Look here: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/649